# Polymer readonly input toggle

Tags: polymer

I am tryint to achieve a readonly toggle on an input in polymer.

```
<input type="text" readonly />
```

But readonly if a property = "m2" something like that.

In angular it was really easy :)

---

```
{{miktarReadonly}} --> this renders
<input type="number" {{miktarReadonly}} --> this does not render min="1"  value="{{ Miktar::input }}" placeholder="{{Hizmet.Birim}}" class="form-control" />
...
 Polymer({
            is: 'hizmet-siparis',
            extends: 'tr',
            properties: {
                .

                miktarReadonly: {
                    type: String,
                    notify:true,
                    computed: '_miktarReadonly(Hizmet)'
                },
        ...
        _miktarReadonly : function (hizmet) {
            if (hizmet && hizmet.Birim !== "m2") {
                return "readonly";
            }
            return "";
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried few things and this works. It renders readonly attribute if the computed property is true, not if falsy. Thx for help all.

```
    <input type="number" readonly$="{{miktarReadonly}}" />
...

    miktarReadonly: {
                        type: String,
                        notify:true,
                        computed: '_miktarReadonly(Hizmet)'
                    },
    ...
  _miktarReadonly : function (hizmet) {
                        return (hizmet && hizmet.Birim == "Tek Fiyat"); // True or Falsy thing
                    },
```